# Need to restart numbering when it gets to 1 and jump to 99

Tags: ios, swift

How would I go about doing this? the code I have is

```
let myInt = Int(currentSaleLabel.text!)
    let sale1Number = (myInt! - 1 + 100) % 100
    let sale2Number = (sale1Number - 1 + 100) % 100
    let sale3Number = (sale2Number - 1 + 100) % 100
    let sale4Number = (sale3Number - 1 + 100) % 100
    let sale5Number = (sale4Number - 1 + 100) % 100
    let sale6Number = (sale5Number - 1 + 100) % 100
    let sale7Number = (sale6Number - 1 + 100) % 100
    let sale8Number = (sale7Number - 1 + 100) % 100
    let sale9Number = (sale8Number - 1 + 100) % 100
    let sale10Number = (sale9Number - 1 + 100) % 100
```

This works fine for numbers 0-99 but I need to eliminate the number 0 also.

Comment: All of those `!` in your code are crashes waiting to happen. Wait until the user types "A" into the text field or leaves it blank.

Comment: @rmaddy Well as of now it should only be numbers cause only the number keyboard pops up but how would I avoid using them? Without them I get an error that says, "value of optional type 'string?' not unwrapped"

Comment: Keep in mind that the keyboard is irrelevant. A user can paste any text into the text field. To eliminate all of the `!` you need to safely unwrap using `if let`. That's covered quite well in Apple's "The Swift Programming Language" book.

Comment: Where are you doing that,inside a loop? Show more relevant code.

Comment: @rmaddy Okay thanks I'll start trying to implement that

Comment: @Dasem I have updated my code with help from @.dasblinkenlight but I now need to eliminate the number 0. I know the above code is probably not the most efficient way to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to make a limit of 99 with modulo `%` operator, like this:

```
let sale1Number = (myInt! - 1 + 100) % 100
```

This decrements `myInt`, and wraps it to 99 when it gets negative. Adding 100 prior to applying `%` has no effect on numbers in range 0..99. Negative numbers above -100 will get processed correctly.

> I am actually also trying to avoid the number 0

You can use a modified formula, like this:

```
let sale1Number = (myInt! - 2 + 100) % 100 + 1
```

Comment: this works great but I am actually also trying to avoid the number 0 which is my fault as I didn't clarify this in my original question. Any ideas as to how I would do this?

Comment: @Baker2795 You can shift the result by one, like this: `(myInt! - 2 + 100) % 100 + 1`

Comment: This works to eliminate 0 but now it is showing '100' instead of '0'

Comment: @Baker2795 If you want to get 99 instead, replace both `100`s with `99`s.